# lim inf and lim sup convergence/divergence

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

Assume that the following sequences are positive, then the statements:

If $\lim \inf a_{n} > 1$, then $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ diverges.

If $\lim \sup a_{n} = 0$, then $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k}$ converges.

Are both true, correct? However I'm just having trouble visualizing it. What exactly are these statements saying? And what's an example of each? I really just want to be able to see it in a picture because I have a hard time conceptualizing the idea of $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$.

Comment: Are these supposed to be sequence of positive numbers?  If not, then the second one seems to be false.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE You're right. For example, the sequence that is $0$ for even $n$ and $-1$ for odd $n$ is a divergent sequence, but satisfies the $\limsup$ condition.

Comment: Yes these are sequences of positive numbers. I will specify that in my post. Could you give me a counterexample to the 2nd statement?

Comment: @Adrian I just did

Comment: Okay, but the statement holds if the sequence is positive, right?

Comment: The second one is definitely false, as the classic harmonic series $a_n=1/n$ shows. (Note, by the way, that for positive sequences, $\limsup a_n=0$ is equivalent to $\lim a_n=0$.) The first one is true, even under the weaker assumption that $\liminf a_n>0$: if $\liminf a_n=\ell>0$, then there exists $N$ such that $a_n>\ell/2$ for all $n>N$, and so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k > \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \ell/2=\infty$.

Comment: Wait, is lim sup of $1/n$ 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lim \inf a_n > 1$, $a_n$ cannot converge to $0$. So the series diverges and the first statement is true.

For $a_n =\frac{1}{n+1}$, we have $\lim \sup a_n = 0$. As for a sequence converging to $l$, $\lim \inf = \lim \sup = l$. However, $\sum a_n$ diverges. So the second statement is false.